# Can we add comments on index in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one index in oracle say "TEMP_INDEX" and i want to add one comment on it like "OBSOLETE" so that i can ignore this index for further processing.

Can we do this? or is there any other way to do this.

Here the aim is, i just want to mark index in some way so that it won't be considered for further processing. Here the constraint is, i can't delete that index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply disable the index by

```
alter index TEMP_INDEX invisible
```

OR as you mentioned that you don't want the system to consider that index for further processing you can use `NO INDEX hint` in your query

Referenced from [ORACLE GUIDE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements006.htm#BABHJBIB) ->

```
SELECT /*+ NO_INDEX(employees emp_empidx) */ employee_id 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE employee_id > 200;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i think making invisible will work for me.

Comment: @seetendra Please mark the post as answered if your question has been resolved.

Comment: Sure :)   will do that

Comment: That's a wrong syntax to disable the index. Moreover we can disable only function-based index.

Comment: @PirateX Caution: the index is then invisible, but it is still there and is still maintained during updates, inserts and deletes. As seentra said that it's obsolete, this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the Index to be used you can make the `Index` `Invisible` - from Oracle 11G onwards.

Syntax - `ALTER INDEX index_name INVISIBLE;`

So a query using the indexed column in the WHERE clause ignores the index and does a full table scan.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: @seetendra - glad to help